# how to display emoticons on UI or in browser?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, utf-8, emoticons

I have developed website in Java. Emoticons in the text are getting displayed as "?". though I have set following property in my javascript, jsp and html pages

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Emoticons are getting displayed properly in java console using but not in the browser or User Interface

```
system.out.println
```

Am reading the text from MongoDb, code is something like below

```
DBObject obj = cur.next();
twitterObj.add(gson.fromJson(obj.toString(), TwitterDbObject.class));
```

So when i write obj.toString(), it converts json to string.

If i try to replace the emoticons using following regex, it works but I don't want to replace, I want to display them

```
String text=obj.toString().replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7f-\\x80-\\xad]","" );
```

Sample text:

```
my mom ordered me my iwatch
```

This emoticon, gets displayed in java console but not in browser. In the browser it gets displayed as "?"

Kindly, suggest a solution for this problem
Thanks

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: I am reading the text from MongoDb, edited my question to include the code details